# Piping Answers to a Second Survey to be Automatically Submitted on Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, survey, qualtrics

I have a long questionnaire (survey-1) on Qualtrics and want to receive a response summary as pdf after each participant. However, I don’t want the whole questionnaire and embedded data to be shown on this file. To solve that, I created a second survey (survey-2) which only consists of the selected questions that I am interested in seeing. The idea is that the participant will fill out survey-1, when they submit it, survey-2 (a shorter version of survey-1) pipes the answers from survey-1 and gets submitted automatically, sending me the response summary. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

I know how to pipe answers from one survey to another, but this leads the participant to the second survey and submitting it as well. I want the participant to fill out the first survey only and submit it once. The process of survey-2 piping answers and sending a response summary to me should run in the background.

Comment: While your question is perfectly valid, it is not a programming question and thus does not belong on this site.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, I am new on this website. Qualtrics may require to use JavaScript for further customization. That is why I thought this place could be suitable for that. Is there any other website you may suggest? Thank you, and sorry for the confusion.